# Angular material chips multi selection issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was looking at the OOTB mat chips examples

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yeehxp?file=src/app/chips-autocomplete-example.html

Goal: To be able to to do multiple selections

Issue: In the stackblitz, Click/select any fruit, and then at the cursor try selecting another. It is not showing the list of available fruits

I had to lose focus and come back, then it is showing item list again. This will confuse user and so unwanted

Is there a way to avoid clicking somewhere else just to select another item/chip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has a directive for this use case. The directive is called [matAutocompleteTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocompleteTrigger). You can call this directive with another reference. Using the reference, you can call a method called [openPanel()](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts#L242). In the example below, I have added two lines to your input. This should give you the result you want.

```
<input
  placeholder="New fruit..."
  #fruitInput
  #trigger="matAutocompleteTrigger"
  [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
  [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true"
  [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
  [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
  (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
  (click)="trigger.openPanel()">
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Not sure why the OOTB doesnt work smoothly